# How best to execute this inner join in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, inner-join

Below is the sample data

```
  acct <- c("000012345","000122452","000122552","000122621","000122201","000122365")
  run <- c("00000","00000","00000","00000","00000","00000")
  ein <- c("11111","22222","33333","44444","55555","11111")
  succuiacct <- c("","","","","","")
  succrun <- c("","","","","","")

 first <- data.frame(acct, run, ein, succuiacct,succrun)

 acct2 <- c("000012345","00012346","000122452","000122453","000122365","000122777")
 run2 <- c("00000","00000","00000","00000","00000","00000")
 succuiacct2 <- c("000200100", "000122914","000200101","000122995","000200102","0001233222")
 succrun <- c("00000","00000","00000","00000","00000","00000")


 second <- data.frame(acct2, run2, succuiacct2, succrun)

  first$identifier <- paste0(first$acct,first$run)
  second$identifier <- paste0(second$acct2, second$run)
```

the goal is to populate the first table with the matching succuiacct2 values when the first.acct + first.run and second.acct2 + second.run2 values are the same. I know that all the run values are 00000 in this example but in the bigger data set, I need to basically concatenate them and make them into a unique identifier. The end result should only have two rows that have a populated succuiacct because they are only three acct values that have an exact match in the acct2 column.

end result would appear as such

```
   acct          run          ein         succuiacct          succrun
000012345      00000        11111       000200100              00000
000122452      00000        22222       000200101              00000
000122552      00000        33333       "Blank"                "Blank"
```

Comment: When you say `+` do you mean addition or 'and'?

Comment: @ Hugh.. the + is an effort to create a two-part or concatenated identifier. The identifying item would the combination of the acct and the run. I know that my example has run values of 00000 but in theory if it was 00001 for a firm.. it would mean a second location like what you find in fast food restaurants

Answer (score 0):

```
dplyr::inner_join(first, second, by = c("acct" = "acct2", "run" = "run2"))
```

Output:

```
       acct   run   ein succuiacct succrun.x succuiacct2 succrun.y
1 000012345 00000 11111                        000200100     00000
2 000122452 00000 22222                        000200101     00000
3 000122365 00000 11111                        000200102     00000
```

Notes:

1. Don't use `"Blank"` for empty values, use `NA`
2. Where did the blanks come from in the first place anyway, as the actual data doesn't have blanks in those rows (see above output)?

Comment: the blanks come about because not every row/entry in the first table has a matching row in the second. Not to give too much shop talk about the first is a fictionalized list of employers and the second is employers that have changed ownership, names, been bought out, ceased operation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not spell out things as succinctly as I should have so can't blame anyone for not solving this. However, came across a construct similar to below and retrofitted it.. and it worked

```
   for (i in 1:nrow(first)) {
   if (first$identifier[i] %in% second$identifier) {
   match_index <- which(second$identifier == first$identifier[i])


   first$succuiacct[i] <- second$succuiacct2[match_index]
   first$succrun[i] <- second$succrun[match_index]
     }
   }





    first <- first[, -which(names(first) == "identifier")]
```